# How to display a website's captcha using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using HttpClient to post data to a website so that I can login to my account,  but on the sign in page there is a Google recaptcha that needs to be solved. How could I either

A) Display the captcha in a windows form so I could solve the captcha

Or

B) Include post data that bypasses/submits the needed response for the captcha?

Comment: How can you automate submission to a site which has a control specifically designed to stop people from automating submissions? Is that really your question?

Comment: i don't think so developers of api/website would give you captcha if that meant to be used as API. so there would be another API endpoint for that if not you should contact them instead of bypassing their security. or finding a way around

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? As @Damien_The_Unbeliever says, the whole purpose of a captcha is to prevent this sort of thing.